# CSS Text-highlighting

Tags: css, text, selection, highlighting

I beleive that I have a CSS related problem with my site. When I highlight text on some pages, the color is white, on others the highlighted text is transparent.

Comment: `color` is set to #FFF for `::selection` for the text. Change it to another color of your choosing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I have changed and I still get the same selection color. What is strange is that when I am logged in on my site I get the color that I want but when I visit my site as a user i get this white color.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the below CSS or Change it to Other Color from your Internal CSS

```
::selection {
    color: #fff;
}
```

It Works.. Have a nice day

Comment: I have changed and removed but unfortunately I still get the same selection color. What is strange is that when I am logged in on my site I get the color that I want but when I visit my site as a user I get this white color.

Comment: ::selection {
    color: Dodgerblue !important;
}
Please Include this css in your File

Comment: I tried that also.As I said when I make these changes I am able to get the result when I am logged in but as a visitior it's the same, I get white text selection.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you guys! I was able to fix it by disabling Fast Velocity Minify plugin.